# How to prove that every Cauchy net in a complete metric space is convergent?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, cauchy-sequences, complete-spaces, nets

> How to prove the basic fact that every Cauchy net in a complete metric space is convergent?

My definition:

> A metric space $X$ is complete iff every Cauchy sequence in $X$ is convergent.

I don't know how to extract a Cauchy sequence from the Cauchy net. If this can be done, then the problem is done. This is my thought and approach.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/187709/857214

Comment: this will help you