# Exercise 2.5.8 Pedersen's Analysis Now

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, analysis, banach-spaces

I'm trying to do the following problem, and I'm getting hung up on one part.  Here is the problem:

Let $f: X \longrightarrow \mathfrak{X}$ be a continuous map from a compact Hausdorff space $X$ into a Banach space $\mathfrak{X}$, with $\mu$ a Radon measure on $X$.  Consider elements of the form: $$I_{\lambda}(f) = \sum_{k=1}^n f(s_k)\mu(E_k)$$ where the $E_k$'s are Borel sets partitioning $X$ and $s_k \in E_k \subset \{s \in X \: | \: \lvert f(s)-f(s_k) \rVert \leq \epsilon \}$ for $\epsilon > 0$.  With $\lambda = \{E_1,\dots,E_n,\epsilon\}$, prove that $(I_{\lambda}(f))_{\lambda \in \Lambda}$ is a convergent net.  We denote the limit by: $$\int_{X} f(s) \: d\mu(s).$$

My main issue I'm having is what the ordering needs to be on the set $\Lambda$.  I figured at first that I would want something like $\lambda \leq \mu$ if and only if $\mu$ contains a refinement of the partition in $\lambda$, and $\epsilon_{\mu} \leq \epsilon_{\lambda}$.  However, this doesn't seem to work, as the smaller the $\epsilon$ I stipulate, this seems to directly affect how many $E_k$'s I would need in my partition since $E_k \subset \{s \in X \: | \: \lVert f(s)-f(s_k) \rVert \leq \epsilon\}$.  Hence if $\epsilon > 0$ was really small, I should expect there to be many more $E_k$'s as $\mu(\{s \in X \: | \: \lVert f(s)-f(s_k) \rVert \leq \epsilon\}) \longrightarrow 0$ as $\epsilon \rightarrow 0^{+}$.

Thus, my point is that I shouldn't be able to just change $\epsilon$ independently of changing the $E_1,\dots,E_n$.  But this goes against what my ordering is supposedly okay with.

Is there another ordering I'm supposed to be using?

Comment: You could show that the elements $I_{\lambda}$ converge to the Bochner integral of $f$. Though, it seems like this exercise is meant to define the Bochner integral in this special case.

Comment: What would the ordering on the set $\Lambda$ be in order to discuss convergence?

Comment: I don't understand the problem with the ordering you've described.  What's wrong with $\epsilon$ effecting the number of $E_k$'s you need?

Comment: Well I ideally want to prove that for any $\delta > 0$ that there exists $\lambda' \in \Lambda$ such that $\left\lVert I_{\lambda}(f) -I_{\mu}(f)\right\rVert \leq \sum_{k=m+1}^n \lVert f(s_k) \rVert \mu(E_k) < \delta$ whenever $\lambda \geq \mu \geq \lambda'$.  However to do this, I need to make $\mu(E_k)$ small for each $k$.  This can be done by making the $\epsilon > 0$ small so that $\mu(E_k) < \epsilon$.  However for $\epsilon > 0$ small, the sum $\sum_{k=m+1}^n \lVert f(s_k) \rVert \mu(E_k)$ now contains a ton of terms since the refinement is very large.

Comment: @MW The issue I see with the refinement being very large is that I can't choose $\epsilon > 0$ to seemingly make up for how many terms are in the sum, as the smaller the $\epsilon$ is, the more terms I have.  So I cant do like an $\epsilon/2^n$ type of argument.

Comment: It is a bit confusing to use $\mu$ for both your measure and for your partition.

Comment: I do see what you're saying about the proof, though, I misinterpreted your question as being whether the ordering is valid, I will think some more on the proof.

Comment: I think everything should still work fine, though, if you just take $\epsilon'<\epsilon/\mu(X)$, right?  It shouldn't matter how many terms there are in the sum.

Comment: Then you would just get $\sum_{k=m+1}^n \lVert f(s_k) \rVert \mu(E_k) \leq (n-m-1)\lVert f \rVert_{\infty} \frac{\delta}{\mu(X)}$ which is still tending to $\infty$ for larger and larger $n$.   So the measure $\mu(E_k)$ must be less than something like $\delta/2^k$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proposed ordering works fine.  To be precise, we should say that $\Lambda$ consists of triples $(\{E_1,\dots,E_n\},\epsilon,\{s_1,\dots,s_n\})$ with each $s_k\in E_k$, and $(\{E_1,\dots,E_n\},\epsilon,\{s_1,\dots,s_n\})\leq (\{F_1,\dots,F_m\},\eta,\{t_1,\dots,t_m\})$ if $\eta\leq \epsilon$ and each $F_l$ is contained in $E_k$ for some $k$.

Then given $\epsilon>0$, choose a partition $\lambda_0=(\{E_1,\dots,E_n\},\epsilon_0,\{s_1,\dots,s_n\})$ with $\epsilon_0<\frac{\epsilon}{\mu(X)}$.

(To see that such a partition exists, note that at each $x\in X$, we have by continuity a neighborhood $U$ where $\|f(y)-f(x)\|<\epsilon/2$ for $y\in U$.  By compactness there is a finite cover $U_1,\dots,U_n$ of $X$ of such neighborhoods, and so we may take $E_1=U_1$, $E_k=U_k\backslash\bigcup_{j<k}E_j$ as our partition, and may choose any points in $E_k$ as our $s_k$.)

Then for any partition $\lambda=(\{F_1,\dots,F_m\},\eta,\{t_1,\dots,t_m\})$ with $\lambda\geq \lambda_0$, we have each $F_l$ contained in some $E_{k_l}$, so we can estimate

\begin{align*}
\|I_\lambda(f)-I_{\lambda_0}(f)\| &=\left\|\sum_{k=1}^nf(s_k)\mu(E_k) -\sum_{l=1}^m f(t_l)\mu(F_l) \right\| \\
&= \left\|\sum_{l=1}^mf(s_{k_l})\mu(F_l) -\sum_{l=1}^m f(t_l)\mu(F_l) \right\|\\
&= \left\|\sum_{l=1}^m(f(s_{k_l})-f(t_l))\mu(F_l) \right\|\\
&\leq \sum_{l=1}^m\left\|(f(s_{k_l})-f(t_l)) \right\|\mu(F_l)\\
&\leq \epsilon_0\sum_{l=1}^m\mu(F_l) = \epsilon_0\mu(X)<\epsilon\text{.}
\end{align*}

It quickly follows that the net is a Cauchy net, hence by completeness of $\mathfrak X$ [the net converges.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/187709/1210477)

Comment: This looks correct, but I'm not sure what uniform continuity means for a general top. space.

Comment: Yeah sorry not sure what I was thinking with that.  Let me adjust

Comment: @Isochron I've edited to make it work now.

Comment: What are you doing in the second equality?  I see that you have some subcollection $E_1,E_2,\dots,E_{n,1}$ whose union gives you $F_1$, but what is happening to the points $s_1,\dots,s_{n,1}$ to be replaced with $s_{k_1}$?

Comment: Each $E_k$ is partitioned into a finite union of the $F_l$'s, so we can sum over each $F_l$, and then $k_l$ is the index $k$ corresponding to the element $E_k$ that contains $F_l$.

Comment: I think in your comment you have it backwards, $\{F_l\}$ is refining $\{E_k\}$, not the other way around.

Comment: I'm getting hung up on the fact that there are now more $s_{i}$'s in the second line, since m is presumably larger than n, so unless there are repeats, I don't see how that works.

Comment: There are indeed repeats.  So really, each $E_k$ is split into $F_{l_1}\cup F_{l_2}\dots \cup F_{l_p}$, then $f(s_k)\mu(E_k)$ becomes $f(s_k)\mu(F_{l_1})+\dots+f(s_k)\mu(F_{l_p})$.  So we define $k_{l_i}:=k$ for each $i=1,\dots,p$.

Comment: I see, thank you